# Store base64 encoded string in HBase

Tags: java, mongodb, base64, hbase, cloudera

I have a very specific requirement of storing PDF data in Hbase columns. The source of Data is Mongo DB, from where the base64 encoded data is read and I will need to bulk upload it to Hbase table.

I realized that in base64 encoded string there are a lot of "\n" character which splits the entire string into parts. Not sure if it is because of this, but when I store the string as it is, using a put :

```
 put.add(Bytes.toBytes(ColFamilyName), Bytes.toBytes(columnName), Bytes.toBytes(data.replaceAll("\n","").toString()));
```

It is storing only the first line from the entire encoded string. Eg :

If the actual content was something like this :
"JVBERi0xLjQKJaqrrK0KNCAwIG9iago8PAovQ3JlYXRvciAoQXBhY2hlIEZPUCBWZXJzaW9uIDEu
" +
                "MSkKL1Byb2R1Y2VyIChBcGFjaGUgRk9QIFZlcnNpb24gMS4xKQovQ3JlYXRpb25EYXRlIChEOjIw\n" +
                "MTUwODIyMTIxMjM1KzAzJzAwJykKPj4KZW5kb2JqCjUgMCBvYmoKPDwKICAvTiAzCiAgL0xlbmd0\n" +

It is storing only the first line which is  :
JVBERi0xLjQKJaqrrK0KNCAwIG9iago8PAovQ3JlYXRvciAoQXBhY2hlIEZPUCBWZXJzaW9uIDEu

in the column. Even after trying to remove the "\n" manually it is the same output.

Could someone please guide me in the right direction here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve it. The issue was when reading the Base64 encoded data from MongoDB Source. Read the data from Mongo DB document DBObject as:

> jsonObj.get("receiptContent").toString().replaceAll("\n","")

And stored it as such in Hbase. Even from the Hue HBase UI Browser I can see the PDF content now.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, I am also working on Base64 encoding. As per my understanding, you should try using 
    `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Base64.encodeBytes(byte[] source, int option)` 
method where `DONT_BREAK_LINES` can be used as an option.
Please let me know if this works fine.